# remove empty from table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In a special stage of my profgram , I want to change the rows hieght , this works but there is a gray empty space still in the table as shown in the image 
 [image]

i tried the following

```
jTable1.setRowHeight(60);

jTable2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(120,225));
jTable2.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(120,225));
jTable2.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(120,225));
```

but the size of the table does not changed. Any solutions?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.

Comment: don't use setXXSize **ever**, for reasons see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657

Comment: layout problems are always solved ... by the layoutManager (as already noted in the comments to @MadProgrammer answer). So first, exactly define what you want to reach in which context.

Comment: @kleopatra thanks any way , what i want exactly is the following : when i change the width of the rows while the program is running , the rows width changes but the size of the table does not change , it remains fixed.
I hope i could explain the problem better now

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [`JTable.setFillsViewportHeight`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setFillsViewportHeight%28boolean%29)

Table fillsViewportHeight = false

[image: Without]

Table fillsViewportHeight = true

[image: With]

Comment: First, why? Second, you might like to have a read through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi

Comment: because the view or the shape will not be beautiful and the row will look not equals

Comment: In that case, set the viewport background color to the same color as the table's background.

Comment: The size of the table is dependent on a number of factors.  The first been the size of the tables content, the second been the layout manager of it's parent container

Comment: Use `frame.pack()` and the size will be good. Note that this does not resize the table, but rather the parent container

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks but last question : what is layout manager of table parent container??

Comment: +1 for `setFillsViewportHeight()`. Maybe `setPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`, followed by `pack()`?

Comment: @CalmSea The size of the table can be altered to meet the requirements of the layout manager of table's parent container (ie, when you add a table to a scroll pane, you are adding to a `JViewPort` container), this can effect the size of the table.  You need to be careful with `JTable` as changing the preferred size could result in the table truncating it's contents.  Better to let the `JTable` calculate it's requirements and manipulate the size through a layout manager. Try changing the view ports layout manager to something like `BorderLayout` for example

Comment: @trashgod setting the scrollable pref is nearly as bad as using settXXSize. Nearly because the default implementation doesn't do much useful in core (JXTable uses the visibleRowCount/ColumnCount properties to calculate the pref in px)

Comment: @kleopatra: Agree; bad habit from aqua's awkwardly large default vertical dimension. Mindful of these [caveats](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), would overriding `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` be reasonable?

Comment: @trashgod that's what JXTable does, so guess my answer :-) To (maybe) be clearer: don't do it on the application level but on a mini-framework level. For finer-grained control, use an appropriate LayoutManager